# MySQL Query with Multiple Select options

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I'm a designer and not developer, so I don't even know HOW to ask this question.

I have a select box in my script and it shows only one user type. But I need it to show more user types, for example, user_type 2, but Ive tried adding AND / OR and it doesnt work.

Heres the script code.

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT id,email,username FROM ' . $dbacct . '
WHERE user_type="3" ORDER BY username ASC', $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Heres the full line

```
<select class=\'widtha\' name=\'contact_user\'>
                ';
                $result = mysql_query ('SELECT id,email,username FROM ' . $dbacct . ' WHERE user_type IN ("2","3") ORDER BY username ASC', $link) or die(mysql_error());

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
                {
                    $row = safe_data ($row, 'display');
                    echo '<option value=\'' . $row['email'] . '\'';
                    if ($row[id] == $_POST[contact_user])
                    {
                        echo ' selected=\'selected\'';
                    }

                    echo '> ' . $row['username'] . '</option>';
                }
                echo '</select>
```

Please can someone help me.
Anton

Comment: For one thing, you're escaping single quotes in your entire code. Instead of `<select class=\'widtha\' name=\'contact_user\'>` you should be doing `<select class='widtha' name='contact_user'>` and do the same for the rest. You only need to escape double quotes when echoing/wrapping in single quotes.

Comment: This for example `echo ' selected=\'selected\'';` should be `echo 'selected=\"selected\"';`

Comment: This line `echo '> ' . $row['username'] . '</option>';` will definitely give you a hard time with the `'> ` and this `echo '</select>` should be `echo '</select>';` at best. I suggest you find and study PHP tutorials on how to echo, and the use of single and double quotes. An hour of reading will definitely help you to have a bit of developing "blood" into you ;-)

Comment: Instead of `' . $dbacct . '` you should be doing `'" . $dbacct . "'`

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I'll have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result = mysql_query ('SELECT id,email,username FROM ' . $dbacct . '
WHERE user_type IN ("1","2","3",....) ORDER BY username ASC', $link) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Hi Aaron, thank you, must be honest, that didn't work. Even though I removed .... after "3," 

I got a php script error on line 166

Comment: It seems Im not getting the error now, BUT it does not give me 2 options in the select list, if I make it "2", "3"